# Getting data from JSON with React mapping

Tags: reactjs, iteration, mapping, next.js

I know this is probably a question that is easily answered, but I cannot figure it out after a few hours. I am trying to map over [this JSON](https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/34275/episodes) but it keeps saying "props.shows.map" is not a function, however the same works for another bit of data. I am trying to get things like 'id' and 'name' from the data.

The mapping works with this link: [https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=\%22Terrance%20House\%22](https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=%5C%22Terrance%20House%5C%22)

Here is the JSON that doesn't work/can't seem to get the information from: https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/34275/episodes

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import Link from 'next/link'


const ShowLink = ({ show }) => (
    <li key={show.id}>
          <Link as={`/episode/${show.id}`} href={`/episodes/id=${show.id}`}>
            <a>{show.name}</a>
          </Link>
             <style jsx>{`
                li {
                    list-style: none;
                    margin: 5px 0;
                }

                a { 
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: blue;
                    font-family: "Arial";
                }

                a:hover {
                    opacity: 0.6;
                }
             `}</style>
   </li>
)
/*
    <h1>{props.show.name}</h1>
         <p>{props.show.summary.replace(/<[/]?p>/g, '')}</p>
         <img src={props.show.image.medium}/>
*/
const Post =  (props) => (
    <Layout>
    <h1>Terrace House Episodes</h1>
        <ul>
            {props.shows.map(({show}) => (
                <ShowLink key={show} value={show} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    </Layout>
)

Post.getInitialProps = async function () {
   //const { id } = context.query
   //const res = await fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}`)
   //const show = await res.json()
   //const res = await fetch(`http://api.tvmaze.com/seasons/34275/episodes`);
    const res = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/34275/episodes');
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
      shows: data
    }
}

export default Post
```

Comment: Is props.shows an array?

Comment: It's JSON that is fetched from the site.

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so your props.shows was probably returned as an object. It needs to be an array if you want to use the .map function.  Try `console.log(typeof props.shows)` and let me know what it comes back as

Comment: I have two sites listed above, both are json, and one works and one doesn't. I'm trying to figure why the second one doesn't.

Comment: It is an object though, yes. how can I change that into an array?

Comment: I can even console.log(shows[0].id) in the getInitialProps and it gives me the ID. I just want to be able to iterate through the JSON and give each ID, each title, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are attempting to destructure a property (namely the 'show' property) which doesnt exist in your json object when you make your map call.

Heres an example of destructuring (in case you arent familiar):

```
const example= {
  show: 'Seinfeld',
};

const { show } = example;
```

In the last line the **show** property is being taken from the example object and assigned to a variable named show (so the variable show would hold the value 'Seinfeld').

In your code below you are also destructuring a property named show from each json object in the map function call:

```
props.shows.map(({show}) => (
            <ShowLink key={show} value={show} />
        ));
```

In the working json each object has a **show:** property which itself is an object containing data you want.

In the not working json there is no **show:** property so you are attempting to access a property that doesnt exist which would return null.

**So to solve the issue**  in the case of the not working url, you simply need to remove the destructuring:

```
props.shows.map((show) => (
            <ShowLink key={show} value={show} />
        ));
```